# Need Help in understanding the unexpected output in swing code

Tags: java, swing, timer, layout-manager, graphics2d

I have developed an application  to produce the following output:-
[image]

I overrided the JPanel's getPrefferredSize but why i am not observing any changes in the output when i change the size.Even if i set the size to 0,0 the diagram is not translated at all and I get the same output as shown above .

Here is my full code:-

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Skeleton extends JFrame{
Skeleton()
{
super("Donut");
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(400,400);

add(new Board());
setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new Skeleton();}});
}
}

class Board extends JPanel
{
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
    RenderingHints rh=new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    //the following statement has no noticeable effect.
    rh.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2.setRenderingHints(rh);
    Ellipse2D e=new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 80, 130);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    for(int deg=0;deg<360;deg+=5)
    {
        AffineTransform at=AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(getWidth()/2,getHeight()/2);
        at.rotate(Math.toRadians(deg));
        //returns a new Shape object after it has been undergone the 'at' transformation.
        g2.draw(at.createTransformedShape(e));
    }
}
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(100,100);
}
}
```

Comment: please format your code with some consistent indentation ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of your layout manager. By default `BorderLayout` ignores preferred size but fills all available space. Use e.g. `FlowLayout` and yu will see the difference.

Comment: :What does 'getWidth()' in the 'paintComponent()' of 'JPanel' return.Is it the width of frame or the width of JPanel,which i have provided in 'getPreferredSize()'.

Is the value returned will be same as returned if I replace 'getWidth()' with 'getSize().getWidth()'.

Comment: The getWidth() returns real width of component. Sometimes it's preferred but in general preferred just tells to layout manager what's desired size. Then layout manager decides how to process the size.